# Why is my cactus losing spikes?

Tags: cactus

So basically i recently got this cactus as a gift. (And is the 1st time owning one) i keep it in sunlight, water it ever 1-2 weeks depending on how dry the soil is, and i keep it in a pot with holes at the bottom. Despite all this i have noticed that some spikes are falling off and others looking weak. Can any one help! (Also does anyone know what type of cactus it is?)[image]

Comment: Without a picture that shows these issues, it's difficult to diagnose. An in-focus picture of the areas where spines are falling out or weak will go a long way towards understanding the issue. Losing spines is not normal and generally happens either from direct physical contact or as a side symptom of rot or other damage/disease/pests.